# Coded UI. How to close window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have .NET desktop application.
In my test I open application and click button to open DocWindow (WinWindow).
After some actions I want to close DocWindow by [X] button.
I tried to record this actions. Recorder generate code:

```
Mouse.Click(uITheRibbonPropertyPage, new Point(926, 15));
```

uITheRibbonPropertyPage is a control in the top of DocWindow.
I think that click on coordinates is not very good idea.
How to close WinWindow by some other way?

Comment: Maybe https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Window.Close Method () used for Window Class from System.Windows. I need method for WinWindow from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls. I think this decision not for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Alt+F4 to close it.

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(yourDocWindowObject, "{F4}", ModifierKeys.Alt);
```